# What is better: one large REST API call or many small for a Cordova/Backbone app?

Tags: rest, cordova, backbone.js

This is my first Cordova/Backbone application.
I have grasped the whole deal with Models, Views, etc. somewhat, and now I have gotten to actually making proper view structure for my app.
It is a user centered app, which means that views are dynamic depending on who the user is and their status in the app.

Could you please help me to understand what is a better choice: making one (large-ish) api call to the server to get the data for all user-related app views (that would get all user info, various menus for the current user etc) and put them in one User model or make several smaller api calls that each get a fragment of the information (let's say, profile information, newsfeed information and options for two menus, so 4 ajax calls total) and keep the models separate? All the relevant views (UserProfile, SideMenu, UserProfileMenu and ActivityFeed) are rendered on user login. Some of them are available for user at all times (SideBar menu for example), some get switched out as user navigates elsewhere.

I design the server-side API myself, so I can freely choose what data is returned and when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"it depends". If you need all the info (from 4 ajax calls) from start, it would be better to create one big api call, because callig server 4 times will last longer than one big call - 4x server ping time. you could use the big call on app start and still create the 4smaller ones to refresh data when needed.

Comment: Thanks, I will take this approach now and see what happens.